# Using Nook outside the US

Tags: epub, nook

I bought a Nook and I live in Mexico, I've read that you need a credit card to purchase books, but I don't want to buy books from b&n, my question is: do I need to add a credit card in order to use the nook? for example, there's this option where you can load your own ePubs from your computer, and that's the reason why I bought it, will that work without an account or US credit card?

Comment: AFAIK they only use the address of the credit card to verify if you are allowed to buy at an US online shop. I used to be able to buy books for my Sony Ebook, until they checked my address ( it is a Bank of America Credit Card registered at a European address) and then blocked further purchases. My Ebook (Sony) still works without a problem, and so, I expect, will your Nook.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can load ePubs from your computer. I've done this in Israel with both a 1st generation Nook and a Simple Touch.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here.

1. No, you do not *need* to add a credit card.  Adding payment information is only useful if you want to buy books directly from BN.com.
2. Do you need to add an account? No!

With a new Nook (or a freshly reset one)

- Switch on Nook.
- Choose your language.
- Hold the top right button.
- Swipe the screen from top left to top right.
- Press the new "Factory" button.
- Hold down the top right button and tap the bottom right corner of the screen.
- A new "Skip OOBE" button will appear.
- Click it!

You've now skipped the "Out Of Box Experience" and have a Nook which isn't tied to BN.  You can copy ePubs onto it - or do anything else you like.

I do this for my US Nook which I use in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a US-based credit card to activate your Nook. You do, however, need to create a B&N account to activate your device. Once that's done you can hook up the Nook to your computer with USB, it'll be in "mass storage device" mode and you can just copy epub files onto it without a problem.

Source: I've got a Simple Touch with Glowlight myself and do not live in the US.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have a B&N account to access the DRM Protected content purchased through the the Nook Store.  And you only need a credit card(or debit card) if you want to purchase through the nook store using that card.  You can also purchase using gift cards purchased elsewhere or given as a gift.

Any side loaded content that exists with out drm is available without the account.